# Why are healthcare costs so inflated in the USA?

Tags: treatment, surgery

I have seen much more inexpensive non-socialized medicine in places such as Puerto Rico, with equal or greater standards of care and outcomes. I would like to understand why the USA is not like that.

Comment: This question is political and might be on topic for Politics.SE, but it's definitely not about medical science and thus off topic here.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's a political question, not medical.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reason actually, I will try to sum it for you:

1. Doctors in USA is very careful when dealing with patient. They may require several test and check before make the decision about the treat that patient need to take.
2. High administrative cost. Government in most of the developed countries play roles to rule the cost of medicare, but [medical care in USA](https://addresseek.com/category/12/hospital) is different due to [lack of political support](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/080615/6-reasons-healthcare-so-expensive-us.asp) for the government taking a larger role in controlling healthcare costs.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the answer, but as you can see the question is off topic here. Your second point highlighted that it's a political question with your link to investopedia.